# Get the Objects out of a list Java

Tags: java, list, object

Im doing a little text adventure. Im current working on a inventory. I tried to do my inventory with a list:
`ArrayList<Object> inventar = new ArrayList<Object>();`
I initialize Objects as Items:

```
Item holzschwert = new Item("Holzschwert", 1, 5);
                inv.addToInventar(holzschwert);
```

Here's my add Method:

```
    public void addToInventar(Object ...item){
    inventar.add(item);
}
```

But everytime i want to print out my inventory (here's my toString() function) i still get the Hash code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Inventar [ Inventar = " + inventar + " ]";
}
```

and my print method

```
Object test = inv.getInventar();
                String ausgabe = inv.toString();
                System.out.println(ausgabe);
```

and the console log:

```
Inventar [ Inventar = [[Ljava.lang.Object;@281c35ec] ]
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It would make _much_ more sense if you create an interface of every kind of item and use `ArrayList<ItemInterface>` instead. `ArrayList<Object>` is error-prone, as you can see  in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is

```
public void addToInventar(Object ...item){
    inventar.add(item);
}
```

Here `item` is an `Object[]`, because you used varargs (`...`). What you are seeing is the result of calling `toString` on an array.

You want

```
public void addToInventar(Object item){
    inventar.add(item);
}
```

or possibly

```
public void addToInventar(Object... items){
    for (Object item : items)
        inventar.add(item);
}
```

**EDIT**

In addition to this answer, I should point out that you should probably not be using `List<Object>` anyway. `List<Item>` would be better as mistakes like this are more likely to be spotted by the compiler. The signature `addToInventar(Object... items)` should really be avoided like the plague, as it will accept literally *any* sequence of arguments of *any length*. All reference types are `Object`s and all primitives can be autoboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Override the Item class toString() method.

```
class Item{

   @override
   public String toString(){
       //Give your implementation
   }
}
```

Comment: Add the implementation of toString() method of Item class in your question.Also, add rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer stuff = new StringBuffer();
    for (Object item : inventar) {
        stuff.append(item.getName()); // you need a getter for the item name
        stuff.append(" ");
    }

    return stuff.toString();
}
```

Both your inventory and items are Objects. If you just print the objects and not the fields you will only get their memory address as output:

```
Ljava.lang.Object;@281c35ec
```

not the properties you've set up for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the exact format of the output, you can do something like this in your `Item` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

`ToStringBuilder` is part of the Apache Commons Lang library.  If you want it specifically formatted a certain way, then go with @Code Whisperer and write your own implementation.